# Is there a web api to find containing block of an element

Tags: css, cssom

Is there a web API to find containing block of an element?

Containing block official definition is mentioned here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details . I am hoping each element's containing block info is stored somewhere and can be retrieved using some web api.

Answer (score 1):

"Containing block" is an abstract concept, not a concrete one. For this reason, there aren't any APIs in either CSSOM or cssom-view for "retrieving" the containing block of an element, and even if there were, you wouldn't be able to read, change, or render it anyway, so this information isn't going to be of any use to you as an author.

In all likelihood, though, you're asking this [not because you're trying to manipulate this information, but because you just want to be able to visualize an element's containing block for debugging purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That's why it's something I think all browser developer tools should have: because your use case is served by developer tools, not cssom-view.